# Rx.js и утечка памяти - как правильно подписаться на поток внутри другого потока

Tags: angular2, rxjs

Создаю конфигуратор дверей, в котором при изменении какого либо св-ва (цвета\размера\заполнения и т.д.) происходит изменения других свойств у зависимых блоков.
К примеру сервис, который получает коллекцию дверей и устанавливает текущее активное полотно, его номер и предоставляет возможность подписаться на их изменения.

```
private items: BehaviorSubject<Leafs[]>         = new BehaviorSubject([]);
private activeNumber: BehaviorSubject<number[]> = new BehaviorSubject([0, 0]);
private activeLeaf: BehaviorSubject<Leaf>        = new BehaviorSubject(null);

public getItems(): Observable<Leafs[]> {
    /*Обращение к серверу*/
}

public changeStatus(arr: number[]) {
    const items                             = this.items.getValue();
    items[arr[0]]['prop'][arr[1]]['status'] = !items[arr[0]]['prop'][arr[1]]['status'];
    this.activeLeaf.next(items[arr[0]].prop[arr[1]]);
    this.activeNumber.next([arr[0], arr[1]]);
}

public getActiveNumber(): Observable<any> {
    return this.activeNumber.asObservable();
}

public getActiveLeaf() {
    return this.activeLeaf.asObservable();
}
```

Соответственно конкретные компоненты могут получить текущее активное полотно и при его изменении нужным способом отреагировать:

```
/**
*Код компонента
*/
 ngOnInit() {
    //Получаем активное полотно
    this.leafService.getActiveLeaf().subscribe(result => {
        //В зависимости от активного полотна, получаем связанный с полотном декор
        this.decorService.getItems(result.id).subscribe(decors => {
            this.decors = decors;
        });
        //Получаем что-то еще
        this.someExampleService.getItems(result.id).subscribe(res => {
            this.exampleItems = res;
        });
    });
}
```

Правильно ли я понимаю что каждый раз, когда будет меняться активное полотно (пользователь будет долго и упорно кликать по всем коллекциям, пока не найдет нужное полотно) будут создаваться новые подписки. А с учетом, что у нас очень много взаимосвязанных элементов, которые должны знать о состоянии друг друга - становиться очень грустно)).
Как можно оптимизировать данные вложенные подписки?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На самом деле если ты используешь стандартный `HttpClient` при обрщении к серверу, то ничего страшного не случится тк у `Observer` объект есть метод `onComplete()` и при завершении запроса память очищается. Поэтому в твоем примере ты можешь их лепить хоть сотню, никакого жора не будет. Если в плане синтаксиса, то лучше писать так:

```
this.leafService.getActiveLeaf()
.switchMap( result => this.decorService.getItems(result.id) )
.subscribe(decors => {
    this.decors = decors;
});
```

Почему не `flatMap` как в примере выше? Да потому-что `switchMap` опять же завершает поток и очищает память.

Comment: Выбор между `flatMap` и `switchMap` продиктован больше тем какой характер у потоков? которые возвращает в данном случае `this.decorService`. Если это одинарные ответы от `HttpClient`, то разницы почти не будет. Разница будет в том случае если придет новое событие пока не отработает старое или если будет возвращаться поток из нескольких событий. Я согласен с тем что автору, наверное, больше подойдет `switchMap`, но `flatMap` отработает ближе к тому как написан исходный код.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы не создавать новые подписки попробуйте что-то типа:

```
this.leafService.getActiveLeaf()
    .flatMap( result => this.decorService.getItems(result.id) )
    .subscribe(decors => {
        this.decors = decors;
    });
```

Пишу по памяти, если именно в таком виде не получится, напишите сделаю более точный код.